# How to pull the requests to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

Good day! Please tell me how to pull data to obtain information with 3-different tables?

I now have:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_product WHERE order_id = (SELECT order_id FROM oc_order_product ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1)");
```

and

```
EOD;
for($i = 0; $i<count($result->rows); $i++) {
$points = $result->rows[$i]['points'];
$price = $result->rows[$i]['price'];
$counts = $result->rows[$i]['quantity'];
$str .= <<<EOD
```

And these have come from another table, not with **oc_order_product**, and **oc_product_option_value**:

```
$price = $result->rows[$i]['price'];
$counts = $result->rows[$i]['quantity'];
```

How do I add correctly**$result** **oc_product_option_value** and **price**, **quantity**? As has just never tried something goes wrong)

Comment: Why dont you do something like this? SELECT * FROM oc_order_product 
1
ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: what do you want exactly

Comment: Why don't you use `JOINS` if you want to obtain data from multiple tables!